# Scala Play Read: How to Flatten Json containing Array of arrays to model

Tags: scala, play-json

I am looking for a way to define a `Reads` which allows me to map a JSON containing the following structure:

```json
{
    "offers": [
        [
            {
                "id": "1234",
                (etc.)
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

to model such `case class TransportOffer(offers: List[Offer])`

Unfortunately I haven't been able to do this yet. This is my code:

```scala
implicit val transportOfferReads: Reads[TransportOffer] = (
    (JsPath \ "offers").read[List[List[Offer]]].flatMap(r => r.flatten)
    )(TransportOffer.apply _)
```

In this case the flattening is not possible, as flatMap expects another Reads. How would I wrap the flattened List into another Reads?
Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll present 3 options:

1. Flattening in a short reads:

```
case class Offer(id: String)

object Offer {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Offer] = Json.format[Offer]
}

case class TransportOffer(offers: List[Offer])

object TransportOffer {
  implicit val transportOfferReads: Reads[TransportOffer] =
    (JsPath \ "offers").read[List[List[Offer]]].map(x => TransportOffer(x.flatten))
}
```

Then calling:

```
Json.parse(jsonString).validate[TransportOffer].foreach(println)
```

outputs:

```
TransportOffer(List(Offer(1234)))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/PUkve9tFSVWqwdSPXvv75w/2)

2. Explicitly writing `Reads`:

```
implicit val transportOfferReads: Reads[TransportOffer] = (json: JsValue) => {
  json \ "offers" match {
    case JsUndefined() =>
      JsError("offers undefined")
    case JsDefined(value) =>
      value.validate[List[List[Offer]]].map(x => TransportOffer(x.flatten))
  }
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/PUkve9tFSVWqwdSPXvv75w/4).

3. First transform the json, into the model you'd like. For that define a `transformer`:

```
val jsonTransformer = (__ \ "offers").json
  .update(__.read[JsArray].map{o => {
    JsArray(o.value.flatMap(_.asOpt[JsArray].map(_.value)).flatten)
  }})
```

Then, assuming we have the case classes and their formatters:

```
case class Offer(id: String)

object Offer {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Offer] = Json.format[Offer]
}

case class TransportOffer(offers: List[Offer])

object TransportOffer {
  implicit val format: OFormat[TransportOffer] = Json.format[TransportOffer]
}
```

We can call:

```
Json.parse(jsonString).transform(jsonTransformer) match {
  case JsSuccess(value, _) =>
    value.validate[TransportOffer].foreach(println)
  case JsError(errors) =>
    println(errors)
    ???
}
```

Output is:

```
TransportOffer(List(Offer(1234)))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/PUkve9tFSVWqwdSPXvv75w).

Comment: Thanks a lot @TomerShetah for your input. Just to clarify - is there no possibility to flatten the JsArray on Reads?

Comment: @TomerShetah well that would work when TransportOffer only takes one parameter right?

Comment: Yes, for more parameters you need to use the `and` operator